# Beets, the geek's music organizer | condition output path based on genre

Tags: linux, beets

The library organizer i'm using is called beets.

Here's an example of my library:

```
~/Music/$albumartist/$album/$track - $title
~/Music/Eminem/The Slim Shady LP/02 - My Name Is.mp3
```

When importing I want to condition the output based off the genre field, like so:

```
~/Music/Eminem/_edit/02 - my name is.mp3
~/Music/_edit/02 - my name is.mp3
```

So, really what I want is for those tracks with genre field beginning with "_" to be placed directly in the music root folder and not under an album artist subfolder.

Answer (score 1):

Answered in [Beet's Documentation](https://beets.readthedocs.org/en/v1.3.9/reference/config.html#path-format-configuration)

First you'll need to edit the config

```
$ beet config -e
```

then specify the **Path Format Configuration**, for instance let's choose the id3tag *comment* (*default* is how your music will normally be imported as):

```
paths:
    default: $albumartist/$album%aunique{}/$disc-$track $title
    comment:comment: _edit/$album%aunique{}/$disc-$track $title
```

don't forget the spaces below *paths:*, because the config file is in yaml-language (config.yaml)

Be careful how you differentiate directory and tags ($artist).

Another option includes (be creative):

```
paths:
    default: $albumartist/$album%aunique{}/$disc-$track $title
    album:_tmp: temporary/$artist - $title
```